# Problem stiching images from a drone with OpenCV due to a poor quality of the images

Tags: c++, opencv, image-stitching, keypoint

I am working with OpenCV and a quad ArDrone Parrot 2.0.
I'm capturing the images from the bottom camera of the quad and I wish to stitch them in order to get a larger image. I'm trying to detect the squares marked in the images.

I tried to perform keypoint detection with ORB, SIFT, SURF and BRISK  and changing their parameters to different values and there weren't good results from that. 
I am unsure about the quality of the images, so maybe a preprocessing would help?

IMAGES:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mokbA.jpg)  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xPoc.jpg)  [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p65sv.jpg)  [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBgcX.jpg)  [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KurSX.jpg)

Comment: can you provide a [reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of feature matching? 
Also are you able to get yaw reading from drone's Magnetometer? This would help with feature matching since you could rotate the images so that they're aligned.

Comment: In feature matching I tried the basics ( Hamming distance and Euclidean distance, BF matcher and FLANN), but the problem actually is that the keypoints are just a few (and some time they are not good, so the algoritm recognise things i dont like to). I have access to magnetometer readings (I'm working with ROS to connect the ArDrone), but in that case if i align them the images would be the same.

Comment: yes it is possible